# splitting texts in textbox when entering in database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

How can I split or put into another row the words in a textbox when being inserted into MS Access(Database). 
For example, my textbox has these words:
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL

And when the user press the enter button, the following words will be inserted into the textbox, but each words will be in a new row? Like, ABC will be in the first row, DEF will be in the second and so on. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Look into [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for split a text you should do this:

```
string test = "ABC DEF GHI JKL";
string[] splitedText = test.Split(' ');
```

For insert in access use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910977/insert-into-access-database):

```
OleDbCommand CmdSql = new OleDbCommand("Insert into [product] (Kod, [names],price,type," + 
                                       "volume,manufacturer,importer) " +
                                       "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi huh? i didn't down vote your answer. I just marked a check for this one since he's the first one to post an answer. :/ It's the others.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi can you prove that I voted you down?

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi  I down voter.i dont love your answer.and i think your answer is wrong

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ: yes i can prove that , if i delete my answer you will get DownVote Rep +1.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi please answer for help and not for reputation

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ: you caught even before its second time , now don't say wise words to escape. if it repeats once again i directly raise flag to moderator. if you can explain what is wrong guide me i accept and correct my mistakes but dont simply downvote people to put down.

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ: dear you have repeated it again with your dummy Account -> http://stackoverflow.com/users/336204/mohammad?tab=reputation downvoted my answer here ->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811339/why-duplicate-and-more-semicolon-at-end-of-expression-not-cause-error-in-visual/21811352#21811352 if you don't retract your downvotes im going to raise a flag about all your fake accounts.