# why duplicate and more semicolon at end of expression not cause error in visual studio compiler?

Tags: c#, c++

visual studio dose not make any differentfor  duplicate semicolon or one to couse  an error   in compiling code this is against at older compiler rules such as turbo c or another !

thats ok code

```
int x ;;;;;;;
```

and this is ok too !

```
int x;
```

Comment: -1 for the `C#` AND `C++` tag, please be more concrete about what language your asking

Comment: @Paranaix - this happens to apply to both languages. And a few more. If anything, there are far too few languages.

Answer (score 2):

The extra semi-colons are just empty statements in the C++ language. It's not a syntax error, so it compiles fine.

Semi-colons are what end statements, so you can do things like this:

```
int x; int y; int z;
```

all on one line.

Answer (score 0):

`;` is treated as an EMPTY statement.

EMPTY Statement is valid in C# thatswhy it does not cause any compile time errors.

```
int val=40;
if(val > 100)
{
  //do something
}
else
{
 ;  //do nothing
}
```

From MSDN: [Empty Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> An empty-statement does nothing. empty-statement: ; An empty statement
>   is used when there are no operations to perform in a context where a
>   statement is required. Execution of an empty statement simply
>   transfers control to the end point of the statement. Thus, the end
>   point of an empty statement is reachable if the empty statement is
>   reachable.