# inserting splitted text to ms access?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access-2007

How can I insert splitted texts to my ms access database?
I can't seem to find the logic in it. :(
Please help me.

Here are my codes:

This is where i split the texts that are inputted in textBox1, textBox2, and textBox3

```
string items = textBox2.Text;
string[] splittedText1 = items.Split(' ');
string quantity = textBox1.Text;
string[] splittedText2 = quantity.Split(' ');
string price = textBox3.Text;
string[] splittedText3 = price.Split(' ');
```

and this is the code where I will insert those texts to my database:

```
OleDbCommand CmdSql = new OleDbCommand("Insert into [sales] ([productname], productquantity, productprice) VALUES (splittedText1, splittedText2, splittedText3);
```

is this even correct? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute query like this.

```
string[] splittedText1 = textBox2.Text.Split(' ');
string[] splittedText2 = textBox1.Text.Split(' ');
string[] splittedText3 = textBox3.Text.Split(' ');

string _sql = "Insert into [sales] ([productname], productquantity, productprice) VALUES (?,?,?)";
OleDbCommand CmdSql = new OleDbCommand();
CmdSql.Connection = Cnn;

CmdSql.Parameters.Add("@productname", OleDbType.VarChar);
CmdSql.Parameters.Add("@productquantity", OleDbType.VarChar);
CmdSql.Parameters.Add("@productprice", OleDbType.VarChar);

decimal dQty = 0m;
decimal dPrice = 0m;
for (int i = 0; i < splittedText1.Length; i++)
{
    Decimal.TryParse(splittedText2[i], out dQty);
    Decimal.TryParse(splittedText3[i], out dPrice);
    CmdSql.Parameters["@productname"].Value = splittedText1[i];
    CmdSql.Parameters["@productquantity"].Value = dQty;
    CmdSql.Parameters["@productprice"].Value = dPrice;
    CmdSql.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: SQL injection, anyone?  How about a parameterized one?

Comment: Shahrooz has already given this [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21793152/3391751) before.

Comment: Then mark this question a duplicate, provide that address, and do not answer it.  If you _do_ choose to answer it, then answer it properly.

Comment: I can't @DonBoitnott. Why don't you mark this question as duplicate?

Comment: hi @Winky I've tried your answer, but it has an error and it highlights the CmdSql.ExecuteNonQuery(); part. It says: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression. 

IDK where the mismatch occurs.

Comment: What is the datatype of all of three fields?

Comment: oh wait, the datatypes are text, number, and number according to ms access. so, I need to change the varchars? I've tried the OleDbType.Text but it has no syntax like that. I'm using ms-access 2007. @Winky

Comment: You have to convert both value into decimal @chenpai. I have updated my answer please check it.

Comment: @Winky it says: **Input string was not in a correct format.** :/

Comment: Make sure the values are not blank. Because, blank value or null value cannot be converted into decimal. If there is extra space in the value then remove it by unsing Trim() function.

Comment: it's like, one error after another. Here's a new one: **Index was outside the bounds of the array** IDK. Are you willing to help me until this will be solved? @Winky

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49247/discussion-between-winky-and-chenpai)

Answer (score 0):

Splitting gives you an array and thus you either need to write insert statement for each
element of array or use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162982/insert-multiple-rows-using-one-insert-statement-in-access-2010):