# error insert query after install application

Tags: c#

i testing my program and when runed in vs without any error execute !
this is my code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection conect = new OleDbConnection();
            conect.ConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;" + "data source=university.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=sa@a";
            conect.Open();
            OleDbCommand o1 = new OleDbCommand();
            o1.Connection = conect;
            if(button1.Text=="save")
               o1.CommandText = "insert into check_user(name_user,pw_user)values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')";
            else
                o1.CommandText = " select * from check_user WHERE (name_user =  '" + textBox1.Text + "') and (pw_user =  '" + textBox2.Text + "' )";
            o1.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (button1.Text != "save")
            {
                if (o1.ExecuteScalar() == null)
                    MessageBox.Show("wrong user");
                else
                {
                    groupBox1.Visible = false;
                    menuStrip1.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                groupBox1.Visible = false;
                menuStrip1.Visible = true;
            }

            conect.Close();
        }
```

but when execute after install app and run this query error occurs :
http://s4.picofile.com/file/8184692692/qq.png
any query select without error executed but query insert or delete occurs this error
please help me

Comment: Check connection string..

Comment: connections without any problem . when testing vs , any error not exist but when run installed error occurs in query insert and delete

Answer (score 1):

You can't use NonQuery with a "Select".  Try this

```
if(button1.Text=="save")
{ 
   o1.CommandText = "insert into check_user(name_user,pw_user)values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')";
   o1.ExecuteNonQuery();
} 
else
{ 
   o1.CommandText = " select * from check_user WHERE (name_user = '" + textBox1.Text + "') and (pw_user = '" + textBox2.Text + "' )"; 
   o1.ExecuteQuery();
}​
```

Comment: Even in this case, the error occurs . 

query select without any error executed but query insert or delete after install this error occurs

Comment: oledb doesn't support names of fields so you must use a parameter like on the following webpage : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910977/insert-into-access-database