# Linking my aspx Visual Basic registration form to access database

Tags: c#, html, database, ms-access, connection

I have created a web form registration page with 8 different fields (Usernametb, Firstname, Surnametb, Emailtb, Mobiletb, Postcodetb, Passwordtb) (tb=text box)

I have also created a database table in Access that has the right amount of columns for each different textbox.

How would I go about successfully linking my registration form to the database so that every time a user registers, it will automatically save his information in the database? ( I need to be able to add, remove and modify people in my database)

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C: \Users\Zee\Desktop\Computing\Comp\UserData.accdb";
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "insert into [UserData](Username,FirstName,Surname,Email,Mobilenumber,Postcode,Password)values(" + Usernametb.Text + "," + Firsttnametb.Text + "," + Surnametb.Text + "," + Emailtb.Text + "," + Mobiletb.Text + "," + Postcodetb.Text + "," + Passwordtb.Text + ")";
}
```

Comment: Ok, you have these two things, now what's the question? Also, your program is at risk for SQL injection attacks. Check [bobby-tables.com](http://bobby-tables.com) for information on them.

Comment: How would I go about successfully linking my registration form to the database so that every time a user registers, it will automatically save his information in the database?

( I need to be able to add, remove and modify people in my database)

Comment: if you are using parameters in AccessDB do you need to use `?,?,?,?` as parameters? also there are plenty of examples online in regards to how to construct an Insert statement into AccessDB

Comment: @MethodMan I am fairly new to all this programming, still trying to figure out how to do everything. This is just a small project that I'm working on so I wouldn't actually make my database or website fully online. So hopefully people wouldn't be able to "SQL inject" my work.

Comment: regardless of that, you still want to follow best practices as to not adopt bad habits.. do a google search for what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: @MethodMan I have tried googling several different methods but non of them seem to work for me. A lot of the tutorials link the prorgam to SQL instead of Access, although I have to specifically do it on access.

Comment: what about this one it has accepted answer in regards to what I commented on earlier.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910977/insert-into-access-database

Comment: @MethodMan what is this character? " ?,?,?,? "

Comment: it's what access uses as it's parameter.. like `@` is what the parameter token is for Sql Server..

Comment: When I use the "?,?" Parameters it just comes up with errors.  Also I do not have enough rep to take this to chat, is there anywhere else we can discuss this so I can provide screen shots? that might help you identify this

Comment: @MethodMan Any thoughts on my previous comment? thank you

Comment: can you edit your question and show how you are using the `?` these are called Parameters, you need to use the command Parameters .Add function if you update the code I can fix it for you

Comment: @MethodMan I've got quite a few pages open and I'm not really sure which one I'm supposed to be modifying. Is there somewhere else that we can talk on so I can provide screenshots?

Comment: you need to update the initial question and put in where you said you tried using the `?`  in your Insert statement..

Comment: @MethodMan I haven't used the "?" in my insert statement because I don't even know what the insert statement is? Like i said, I'm really new to programming so all of these terms are new to me.