# SQL QUERY Return 0 Records but 2 records exist

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

This code returns zero rows count but there are 2 rows in `appointment` table.

The msgbox I commented was to check if the date is correct and format is correct and shows date as 2014/08/09. The appointment date in database is 2014/08/09 for 2 records (the only 2 records). Record count variable shows 0.

Table name (copied directly cut and paste) is `Appointments` and column is `AppointmentDate`.

The `connectDatabase` sub routine connects to the database successfully as I use it whenever I connect to database so it's correct as I connect to other tables correctly before I run this code using same sub routine.

`Command.text` contains

```
SELECT * FROM Appointments WHERE AppointmentDate = 2014/08/09
```

Don't know what other details to specify.

```
Private Sub frmAppointments_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load             
          'load appointments
           LoadAppointments(dtpAppointmentDate.Value.Date) 
    End Sub

    Public Sub LoadAppointments(whichdate As Date)
           Dim sqlcmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

           'set connection
           ConnectDatabase()

           With frmAppointments
               'MsgBox(whichdate)                   
                M_connDB.Open()
               'fetch records from database
               sqlcmd.Connection = M_connDB
               sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Appointments WHERE AppointmentDate = " & whichdate
               .dataAdapterAppointments = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlcmd.CommandText, M_connDB)
               'first clear data table to prevent duplicates
               .dataTableAppointments.Rows.Clear()
               .dataAdapterAppointments.Fill(.dataTableAppointments)
               M_connDB.Close()

               Dim rowindex As String
               Dim iy As Long
               Dim recordcount As Long

               'check if any records exist
               recordcount = .dataTableAppointments.Rows.Count
               If Not recordcount = 0 Then
                    For iy = 0 To .dataTableAppointments.Rows.Count
                          For Each row As DataGridViewRow In .dtgrdAppointments.Rows
                              If row.Cells(0).Value = .dataTableAppointments.Rows(iy).Item(6) Then
                                  rowindex = row.Index.ToString()
                                  MsgBox(.dtgrdAppointments.Rows(rowindex).Cells(0).Value, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "MSG")
                                 Exit For
                            End If
                          Next
                    Next iy
               Else
                    MsgBox("No Appointments for selected date.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "No Appoinments")
               End If
           End With
```

Comment: Use sql-parameters instead of string-concatenation. `SELECT * FROM Appointments WHERE AppointmentDate = @whichdate`

Comment: Access Database. adding @ stops at .dataAdapterAppointments.Fill(.dataTableAppointments)

Comment: You may need to use the SelectCommand as shown at [DataAdapter Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sql-parameters instead of string-concatenation. This should work in MS Access:

```
sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Appointments WHERE AppointmentDate = ?"
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("AppointmentDate", whichdate)
```

This prevents you from conversion or localization issues and -even more important- sql-injection.

Comment: It is perhaps important to note that as the parameters are not named in the query, they must be added in the order in which they are used. There are some examples which may be useful to the OP at [Parameter Queries in ASP.NET with MS Access](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/26/Parameter-Queries-in-ASP.NET-with-MS-Access) (sorry, my google-fu is weak today).

Comment: Breakpoint still shows code exiting at .dataAdapterAppointments.Fill(.dataTableAppointments) does go further than this line.

Comment: @DeclaredInsane: maybe the synatx is stil wrong. Read about sql-parameters in MS Acess. I'm not sure it named parameters are allowed. Wrap it in a `Try-Catch` and set a breakpoint in the `Catch`. Then show us the error.

Comment: Tried catch, says two or more parameters are incorrect. I'm very new to vb.net.

Comment: Ok change data type from date to string instead of date. Works as I can still compare the string type with date type. Not ideal but works. Thanks a mill for the inspiration!

Comment: Dont choose the wrong datatype, instead try to get it working with parameters. I cannot help now because i have neither an IDE nor Access here and im writing on a phone. I also dont know which driver you use fo the connection. Maybe even named parameters are supported. Play around with prefixing @ before the parameter name. Have also a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216271/whats-wrong-with-these-parameters

Answer (score 0):

`2014/08/09` doesn't have quotes around it, making it a math expression (2014 divided by 8 divided by 9). Of course, your table has no rows with a date matching the result of that expression. But don't put in the quotes. Instead, add a parameter.

Comment: Tried that before posting and still it doesn't go past .dataAdapterAppointments.Fill(.dataTableAppointments). I assume by adding the quotes that it shows that you using a string type? With catch I'm getting data type mismatch when adding quotes.

Comment: Change date type to string in database and it works and can still compare string and date for comparisons if needed. Thanks a mill for inspiration!

Comment: My apologies this is MS Access--so date liberals are like `#2014/08/09#`. But please use parameters. Changing date type to string is **horribly, horribly wrong**. Do not do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't VB, so I write it in C#. My point of view is it's better to specify the datatype too:

```
sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Appointments WHERE AppointmentDate=@whichdate";
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@whichdate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = whichdate;
```