# How to update an entire selected same column?

Tags: c#, oledb

I want to update an entire selected same column with another value...

heres a code i have tried, apparently its not working (the error is no changes in DB)

```
 OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Rock.accdb";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE profile SET [year]=@1 WHERE [year]=@2";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", comboBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", comboBox2.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        label4.Text = "Updated successfully";
        label4.ForeColor = Color.Green;
```

Please be respectful, if you guys have any doubts just comment...

Comment: I guess your `connection string` is not proper. Check it in the config file and it seems that your `UPDATE` query is not proper

Comment: You should probably tag your question "ole", and remove the Visual Studio tag - your problem presumably has nothing to do with Visual Studio.

Comment: ok i will do that... but @NadeemKhan you got me wrong... everything is perfect... except the query... if you guys got any idea regarding that then it would be appreciable...

Comment: This question is similar and may contain the answer you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216271/whats-wrong-with-these-parameters    "The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used."

Comment: i am not specifying anyone here, but do you guys understand my question?  i want to update a column with the same name itself... so is there any alternatives for this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE profile SET [year]=? WHERE [year]=?"
```

and update parameters (the parameters must be added in order of the '?'s in the query)

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", comboBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", comboBox2.Text);
```

Comment: this is the error i get "The OleDbParameterCollection only accepts non-null OleDbParameter type objects, not String objects."

Comment: i updated the answer, try it with AddWithValue and use "?" as the parameter name